# Determine if wmiobject class exists for a given namespace

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, wmi

I have a namespace that I'd like to use to validate the existence of a WMI object before I run a `Get-WmiObject` against it further down in the code. For example, I want to throw the namespace for SSRS 2012 at it and if it doesn't exist on the machine, then I'll try the next namespace for SSRS 2008 R2.

**Is there a way to check for the class's existence, by just guessing a namespace, without throwing an error if it does not exist?**

1. I don't want to have to use a try-catch as the solution. I'd like to know a way that I can get a simple boolean result that tells me whether the class exists in this namespace.
2. I don't want to have to use SilentlyContinue as the solution either.
3. This will be executed from a Powershell job step in a SQL Agent job. This sometimes handles errors differently than pure Powershell, and is the reason for my concern about #'s 1 and 2 above.

Comment: I have updated my answer (actually, restored my original solution) with code that will not throw an error if either the namespace or class name is invalid.

Comment: We got around this issue by capturing the SSRS version like this guy did in the foreach loop here: http://hindenes.com/powershell/SQLReporting.psm1. But I still think this question has value.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `-Class`, `-List`, and `-Namespace` parameters of the [`Get-WmiObject` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849824.aspx) to see if a single class exists in the specified namespace:

```
$class = Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_BIOS' -List -Namespace 'root\cimv2';
$classExists = $class -ne $null;
```

Here's an alternative (but slower) method from [an earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21689643/2) of my answer:

```
$class = Get-WmiObject -List -Namespace 'root\cimv2' `
    | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Win32_BIOS'; };
$classExists = $class -ne $null;
```

Going back to [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21689643/1), here's a third option that, in my testing, does not throw any errors if either the namespace or the class is invalid:

```
$class = Get-WmiObject -List | Where-Object {
    $_.__NAMESPACE -eq 'root\cimv2' -and $_.__CLASS -eq 'Win32_BIOS';
};
$classExists = $class -ne $null;
```

Note that `$_.Name` and `$_.__CLASS` are effectively synonyms.  In each of these code snippets, `$class` will contain a [`ManagementClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx) instance for the class you searched for, if found, otherwise `$null`.

Comment: THANK YOU for explaining the similarity between $._Name and $_.__CLASS  . That was tripping me up as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try your third example (or any of them) $classExists is false even when I know the namespace should be on the machine. The class I'm searching in: `MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting` | The namespace I'm searching for: `root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver\RS_<INSTANCE_NAME>\v11\admin`

Comment: Because I know the correct namespace, I can run `$SSRSClass = Get-Wmiobject -namespace $ns -class "MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting"` and get the `__CLASS` `and __NAMESPACE` listed in the results of `$SSRSClass`. But your methods don't seem to work when I use those same values for `__CLASS` and `__NAMESPACE`.

Comment: If you run `Get-Wmiobject -List -Namespace $ns` does it return nothing, an error, a list of classes not including `MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting`?  And how about just `Get-WmiObject -List`, is that returning classes from the target namespace?  Does the output change if you run from an elevated PowerShell session (not sure if that's applicable to your environment)?

Comment: Running `Get-Wmiobject -List -Namespace $ns` returns a list that includes MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting. But `Get-WmiObject -List` does not.

Comment: @dev_etter Yes, if you don't specify the `-Namespace` parameter it defaults to `root\cimv2`.  I think I was confused on that as well, originally thinking that `-List` will return _all_ classes, when it's really just all classes in the specified (or default) namespace.  But it sounds like my second code snippet does give you the results you need?

Comment: Nice, detailed explanation of what's going on in this answer in [The Scripting Guy's post for July 13, 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090721000328/http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/07/13/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-handle-errors-in-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx) (archived version b/c it retains formatting & images).